# How to copy the header row from initial sheet into newly create sheets

Tags: excel, vba, copy, move

Hi I have used this code to copy data from my overview sheet into current sheets or if the sheet does not exist to create it.  However I am struggling to work out how to add a line or two in the else bit to copy the header row (A1 - G1) from overview into the new sheets also.

```
Sub CopyRows()

Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngCell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim SheetName As String



With Worksheets("Overview")
Set rngMyRange = .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D65536").End(xlUp))

For Each rngCell In rngMyRange

    rngCell.EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Copy

    If (WorksheetExists(rngCell.Value)) Then
        SheetName = rngCell.Value
        Sheets(SheetName).Select
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
        LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Rows(LastRow + 1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Else
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ActiveSheet.Name = rngCell.Value
     Sub copyheadernames()

   End Sub
   End If
    'Go back to the DATA sheet
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Next

End With

End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the sub I'd set a named range covering the overview headers and then in the else section copy that range to the required destination e.g

...
Dim SheetName As String
Dim headings as range

Set headings = Worksheets("Overview").range(A1:G1)

then in else part change the

headings.copy Destination: =

But to do this you'll need to change the point you are inserting the data to leave a blank row for the headers